# Install jonathonf older firefox version

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox

[Jonathon F](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr) has updated the firefox version two weeks ago. Now when I do `apt-get install firefox-esr` the `68` version is installed.

How can I install the previous version, which was `52` (if I'm not mistaken)? `apt-get install firefox-esr-52` does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy version 18.04